# Flutter : admob build success but then crash

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

i work with flutter project and add admob ads . i use firbas-admob from pub div . all well and build success . after that app crash and show this error in picture. how solve that please [image: er]

Comment: Did you add admob_app_id to info.plist?

Comment: Yes . sure . <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>[ADMOB_APP_ID]</string>

Comment: and put my admob app id

Comment: Did you also add GoogleService-info.plist??

Comment: I solve it by add GoogleService-Info.plist  from firebase project

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me also: the app was crashing after opening. Then encountered this on **firebase_admob** package:

AdMob 17 requires the App ID to be included in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Failure to do so will result in a crash on launch of your app. The line should look like:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
```

I've changed `[ADMOB_APP_ID]` to my admob ID ("of course you did, it is self-explanatory from its name"), added that code to `AndroidManifest.xml` and then app stopped crashing.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue too. but at the end, the problem was, that i didn't add the **Google Service file from Firebase** to the project, as it's seems to be required (by the plugin), like [mentioned here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#firebase-related-changes)

Answer (score 0):

This error can be fixed by matching the admob app-id and ad-unit id's. More info in this github issue's comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23659#issuecomment-435264026